# Annoying tips in Pycharm, cant disable

Tags: pycharm

[image]

Every time I am trying to write anything these windows come up and do not go away. If I start a second line than the second window goes right above the first. It is super annoying, how do I fix that? In Google, I only found info to how to turn off inspections but it didn't help.

Comment: Disable [the code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#completion_tips) of what's bothering you or set it with a longer delay.